# RESTHeart and Retrofit POST embedded document with binary data

Tags: mongodb, retrofit, restheart

I am looking to POST embedded document in my collection in MongoDB using RESTHeart by means of Retrofit. This is that this document should be with binary data. If to put json representation of this document it shoule be like this

```
{ 
"id":"5b50aa602f925f13fc3a3da2", 
    "documents":[ 
          {"id":"1", "name":"firstDocument" , "content":BINARY_DATA1}
          {"id":"2", "name":"secondDocument" , "content":BINARY_DATA2}
     ]
}
```

Can someone help on this ?

I've checked documentation and currently did not find out how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just post the json to the collection with binary data encoded in base 64.

Hiwever,for binary data you better use files buckets. But in this case you cannot have two files in one document.

Comment: I've already used buckets and it works good. Thanks Andrea for reply.